# Каким образом можно отрефакторить метод add() метод для Controller?

Tags: java, java-8

Работаю с логикой для `ProjectController` класса, написанного ниже:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project")
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired
    ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Autowired
    ProjectService projectService;

    ProjectAdaptor projectAdaptor = new ProjectAdaptor();

    /**
     * Logger declaration for knowing the flow of execution for debugging
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectController.class);

    @GetMapping("/projects")
    @Operation(summary = "Get list of all projects")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProjectDTO>> findAllProjects() {
        logger.info("findAllProjects() is calling...");

        List<ProjectDTO> projectList = projectService.findAllProducts();
        if (projectList.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(projectList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{companyId}")
    @Operation(summary = "Get list of projects from database based on companyId")
    public @ResponseBody List<ProjectDTO> findAllProjects(@PathVariable("companyId") String companyId,
                                     HttpServletRequest req) throws ErrorHandling {
        logger.info("findAllProjects() is calling : ");
        Long longCompanyId = Long.parseLong(companyId);
        List<Project> projectList = projectService.getAllProjects(longCompanyId);
        logger.info("findAllProjects ProjectList : " + projectList);

        if (projectList != null && !projectList.isEmpty()) {
            return projectAdaptor.databaseModelToUiDtoList(projectList);
        } else {
            throw new ErrorHandling("Project data not present.");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping
    @Operation(summary = "Add new project")
    public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> addProject(@RequestBody Project project) {
        logger.info("addProject() is calling...");

        if (project != null) {
            ProjectDTO projectDTO = projectAdaptor.databaseModelToUiDto(project);
            Project entity = projectRepository.save(projectDTO);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ProjectDTO("","",""), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @PutMapping
    @Operation(summary = "Updating project")
    public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> updateById(@RequestBody Project project) {
        logger.info("updateById() is calling...");

        if (project != null) {
            projectRepository.save(project);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Updated successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ProjectDTO("","",""), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    @Operation(summary = "Deleting project")
    public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> deleteById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        logger.info("deleteById() is calling...");

        Optional<Project> project = projectRepository.findById(id);
        if (project.isPresent()) {
            projectRepository.deleteById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Successfully deleted.", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ProjectDTO("","",""), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Возникла проблема, как отрефакторить метод добавления:

```
@PostMapping
@Operation(summary = "Add new project")
public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> addProject(@RequestBody Project project) {
    logger.info("addProject() is calling...");

    if (project != null) {
        ProjectDTO projectDTO = projectAdaptor.databaseModelToUiDto(project);
        Project entity = projectRepository.save(projectDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ProjectDTO("","",""), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Возник вопрос с тем, нужно ли конвертировать перед сохранением `Entity` в `DTO`. Если да, то будет ли проблемой иметь во входящем параметре `Entity` или лучше переписать логику под это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен за помощь по данному вопросу.

Готов также предоставить любую дополнительную информацию, способную помочь в данном вопросе при необходимости.

Comment: Разве решение не стоит добавлять в качестве ответа?

Comment: @Vestalt, окей, отпишу в ответе без проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итоговое полученное решение:

```
@Operation(summary = "Add new project")
public ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> addProject(@RequestBody Project project) {
    logger.info("addProject() is calling...");

    if (project != null) {
            Project entity = projectRepository.save(project);
            ProjectDTO projectDTO = projectAdaptor.databaseModelToUiDto(entity);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(projectDTO, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ProjectDTO("","",""), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```